# dbexception unhandled by user code

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am getting this `(dbexception unhandled by user code)`

> {"An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner
>   exception for details."}
>
> System.Data.UpdateException

exception on

> db.SaveChanges();

when i enter the data and click on save button.

```
    //POST  Create
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Information info)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Information.Add(info);
            db.SaveChanges(); //In this line shows Error
            return Redirect("Home");
        }
        return View(info);
    }
```

Comment: Add more details about the Exception

Answer (score 0):

Here your (Information info) parameters are maybe empty or more then the character length...

For example info.name ="tttttttt ......";(string with more then 50 character) but in db table you declared as name nvarchar(50)...

check with the db table design and your input yo object....

Answer (score 0):

Do like this to write simplified exception in file, it will tell you exact reason of exception:

```
try
{
    // Your code...
    // Could also be before try if you know the exception occurs in SaveChanges

    db.SaveChanges();
}
    catch (System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException e)
{
    var outputLines = new List<string>();
    foreach (var eve in e.EntityValidationErrors)
    {
        outputLines.Add(string.Format(
            "{0}: Entity of type \"{1}\" in state \"{2}\" has the following validation errors:",
            DateTime.Now, eve.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name, eve.Entry.State));
        foreach (var ve in eve.ValidationErrors)
        {
            outputLines.Add(string.Format(
                "- Property: \"{0}\", Error: \"{1}\"",
                ve.PropertyName, ve.ErrorMessage));
        }
    }
    System.IO.File.AppendAllLines(@"c:\temp\errors.txt", outputLines);

}
```